# Is there any solution to let the character follow 2 path which include 2 different action?

Tags: animation

In this case, i want to do the cat follow the bezier curve path using walking action first follow by another curve path which using jumping action. Izit any better way to do the that?

[image]

Comment: It might be possible but it seems a bit complicated, why don't you use the same curve and just play with the Follow Path Offset or curve Evaluation Time to stop or slow down then restart the cat whenever you want?

Comment: i have abiit confusing..."Follow Path Offset or curve Evaluation Time to stop or slow down then restart the cat whenever you want?" how does it work?

Comment: You can see that if you play with the Offset value of the Follow Path Constraint it will move the armature along the curve, so you can create some keyframes to control the movement of the armature along the curve

Comment: also can use the offset value to stop the character and then continue to move along the path?

Comment: can we set the frame that start move along the part and the end frame to move along the path?

Comment: yes, in the Follow Path constraint, enable the Fixed Position option, then if at a certain frame X you create a keyframe on the Offset, then a frame X+n you create a second keyframe with the same value, it will make the object stop between X and X+n

Comment: what you could also do it select the curve, go in the Graph Editor, on the left panel select Evaluation Time, open the N panel on the right, in the Modifiers tab delete the Generator, then in the Properties panel > Data > Path Animation, manage the movement of the object along the curve with some keyframes on the Evaluation Time value

Comment: Ermmmm. may i ask about if the keyframes are in dope sheet and not in timeline, it can be rendered?

Comment: yes, I think in the Timeline you'll only see the keyframes of the selected object, whereas in the Dopesheet you can either see the keyframes for selected or every objects, depending on the activation of the Only Include Channels option, but what does it have to do with your problem?